# Implication of $L^p$ convergence

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Take $U$ as open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If $u_{m} \rightarrow u$ in $L^{p}(U)$ then does it follow that $||u_{m}||_{L^{p}(U)} \rightarrow ||u||_{L^{p}(U)}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by the triangle inequality (dropping the subscript on the norms):
$\|u\|=\|u-u_m+u_m\|\le\|u-u_m\|+\|u_m\|$, so $\|u\|-\|u_m\|\le\|u-u_m\|$.
Interchanging $u$ and $u_m$ in this and combining the two inequalities leads to $\bigl|\|u\|-\|u_m\|\big|\le\|u-u_m\|$, and the result follows.

Comment: And look at closely Hanche-Olsen's answer and observe that the answer is actually true in any normed linear space; not just the $L^p$-spaces.

Comment: Thanks I understand. I have one more short $L^{p}$ related question: Take $||u||_{L^{p*}(U)} \leq C||Du||_{L^{p}(U)}$ for $1 \leq q \leq p*$ (where $Du$ is the gradient of $u$) then if $|U| < \infty$ we have $||u||_{L^{q}(U)} \leq C||u||_{L^{p*}(U)}$. Can you see how this follows?

Comment: I think you'd better ask that as a separate question, as it doesn't seem that closely related. More of a Sobolev space type question?

Comment: Yes it is but the way it's presented in the proof suggests that it follows simply as a result of properties of $L^{p}$ spaces, but I will re post as a new question.

Comment: I posted the new question under the tags Sobolev Spaces, Lp spaces and Functional Analysis.